# Finding the maximum value of $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2-4a+9}$ s.t. $a+b+c =1$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials

Problem: Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be non-negative real numbers such that $a+b+c =1$. Find the maximum value of
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a^2-4a+9}+\frac{1}{b^2-4b+9}+\frac{1}{c^2-4c+9}.
\end{align}

By using the Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions, I know the maximum occurs at $a=0$, $b=0$, and $c=1$. But I want to know how to solve this problem without using calculus, because it is a math olympiad problem.

Comment: Copied from AOPS [1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h398914p2219896), [2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h467387p2617181).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because$:$
$$\dfrac{a}{18} + \dfrac{1}{9} - \dfrac{1}{a^2-4a+9} = \dfrac{a(a-1)^2}{18(a^2-4a+9)} \geq 0,$$
$$\therefore \dfrac{1}{a^2-4a+9} \leq \dfrac{a}{18} + \dfrac{1}{9}.$$
So$:$ $$ \sum \dfrac{1}{a^2-4a+9} \leq \dfrac{a+b+c}{18} + \dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{7}{18}.$$
Equality occur when $a:b:c=1:0:0$ or any permution.

**Update.** Let
$$f(a) = (\,ma + n\,)(\,a^2-4a+9\,) - 1.$$
We will try to find $m,\,n$ such that $f(a) \geqslant 0$ for all $a \in [\,0,1\,].$

**Proof 1.** Let $a = 0$ and $a =1$ we get
$$\{9n = 1,\; 6(m+n) = 1\}.$$
Solve equation we get $m = \dfrac 1 {18},$ $n = \dfrac 1 9.$

**Proof 2.** Write inequality as
$$f(a) = a \Big[\,a^2m-(4m-n)a+9m-4n\,\Big] +9n-1.$$
It's easy choose $n = \dfrac{1}{9},$ we get
$$f(a) = a \Big[\,ma^2-(4m-n)a+9m-4n\,\Big].$$
For a quadratic polynomial $ma^2-(4m-n)a+9m-4n,$ we have$:$
$$\Delta  = -(10m+n)(2m-n) = -\left(10m+\dfrac 1 9\right)\left(2m-\dfrac 1 9\right).$$
We need $m\geqslant 0.$
So choose $2m = \dfrac{1}{9}$ which means $m = \dfrac{1}{18}.$

Comment: Great solution, but how did you spot the upper bound $a/18+1/9$?

Comment: It's called U.C.T, you can read method [here](https://nguyenhuyenag.files.wordpress.com/2020/08/uct.pdf).

Comment: You don't need a 33-page link to explain "I looked for $A,\,B$ so $(Aa+B)(a^2-4a+9)-1$ is $a$ times a perfect square", which is the obvious way to do it; I asked in case there was some other way to spot the $1/18$ coefficient. But given your link, what interests me is that UCT doesn't seem to go by any easily googled name in English. [The closest I could find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) assumes the context for choosing coefficients by solving simultaneous equations is to understand ODEs or recurrence relations.

Comment: If $f(a) = \frac{1}{a^2 - 4a + 9}$, the line joining $(0, f(0))$ and $(1, f(1))$ happens to be convex to $f(a)$ by a close margin.

Comment: @TobyMak That's an even better way to do it!

Comment: Your method is more rigorous, but I figure quite a few people who are familiar with inequalities will recognise this fact, and just check if the function is convex using the convexity condition.

Comment: @TobyMak The ideal strategy is something of a compromise technique: to spot the linear function we'll use the way you did, then verify the desired inequality as in the above answer.

Comment: UTC is the calling of this in my country, this is tangent line method. Sorry for the inconvenience. I've updated the post.

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag Nice solution! +1 Tangent Line method forever! :D

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

By your work we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2-4a+9}\leq\frac{7}{18}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a^2-4a+9}-\frac{1}{5}\right)\leq\frac{7}{18}-\frac{3}{5}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(2-a)^2}{a^2-4a+9}\geq\frac{19}{18}.$$
Now, by C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(2-a)^2}{a^2-4a+9}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(2-a)^2(4-a)^2}{(a^2-4a+9)(4-a)^2}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(2-a)(4-a)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-4a+9)(4-a)^2}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$18\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(2-a)(4-a)\right)^2\geq19\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-4a+9)(4-a)^2,$$
which after homogenization gives:
$$\sum_{sym}(190a^3b+207a^2b^2+813a^2bc)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.